# Blacklisting Specific From and To with Postfix

Tags: email-server, blacklist, postfix

I have a scenario where I need to blacklist emails from one email to one of our local emails.  Is blocking this specific scenario possible in postfix?

For example, emails from person@fromaddress.com to person@ouraddress.com should be black listed, but not other emails coming from person@fromaddress.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use restriction classes. See:

- http://www.postfix.net/postconf.5.html#smtpd_restriction_classes
- http://www.postfix.net/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html.

For example:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
    smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/protected_destinations
        ...
    smtpd_restriction_classes = bad_senders1
    bad_senders1 = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/bad_senders1

/etc/postfix/bad_senders1:
    person@fromaddress.com   REJECT   You are not welcome here.
    ...

/etc/postfix/protected_destinations:
    person@ouraddress.com    bad_senders1
    ...
```

Now emails with an envelope sender address in the "bad_senders1" restriction class will get rejected, but only if it was sent to an address in the "protected_destinations" list that has the "bad_senders1" restriction class specified on the right-hand side.

Remember to run [postmap](http://www.postfix.org/postmap.1.html) for the newly created files.